# Why does .animate to scrollTop jump to 0 before animating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop, parallax

I am playing with Parallax scrolling like on [that nike site](http://www.nikebetterworld.com/).  So I have been using [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to determine the user's vertical position on the page and then I've been adjusting element's positions based on the changes to that value.

Here I round the scrollTop value and log it.  I'll show the log later.

```
var distance = 60*(Math.round($(window).scrollTop()/60));
console.log(distance);
```

Then, on click, I call this function which scrolls to the scrollTop value that I've passed it.

```
function goTo(n){
    console.log('begin animating');
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: n},2000);
}
```

Here's the problem, the scroll top value jumps to 0 before animating.

So I'll be halfway down the page and it logs:

```
begin animating
0
6240
6180
6120
// etc...
```

The way I'm positioning stuff relies on the accuracy of the scrollTop value. So my question is:

How can I keep the scrollTop value from jumping to 0 before going through with the animation?

Let me know if theres any more info needed.
Heres the live version of the site: http://theblueeyeguy.com/moon/Illumination/

(click 'Next' then 'Prev' to break it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because you're using a link with `href="#"`.

Add `return false;` to your `onclick` attribute.

```
<a href="#" onClick="goTo(2160);return false;">< Prev | </a>
```